# SSAS Tabular - Data is stale

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

I have a tabular model that I've processed and deployed.

I'm having a problem getting SSRS to reflect the newly deployed information. I have a shared Dataset accessing a shared Data Source.  When I run the MDX in the query designer of the Dataset, the correct numbers are returned.  When I run the report, however, the old numbers still show.  I've tried deleting the .DATA file but it didn't help.

**EDIT:**

I've verified that the problem is in the SSAS database itself. I queried it with drillthrough from SSMS and saw that it is returning rows that aren't in the source views any more. They used to be, but no longer.

This almost seems to be some crazy caching issue.  I've rebooted and dropped/redeployed the SSAS database and no luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a few steps.

1. Ensure you are connecting to the correct tabular model.
2. Expand the tables in the tabular model, and right click one of the tables and click "Process".  Check all the additional tables in the model.
3. Change "Process Default" to "Process Full" (Process default does not always work correctly)
4. Click Ok.

You should now see the model process table by table.

Answer (score 1):

I would close and re-open the report.

Actually I would completely ignore the BIDS / Visual Studio Preview pane as it is riddled with bugs and inconsistencies and proves nothing (assuming your end users aren't using Visual Studio).

Instead I would deploy the report for each test run to a test environment / folder on the host server (Report Manager / SharePoint).  As well as being a realistic and meaningful test, this has many advantages such as being able to leave multiple IE tabs open with various parameter combinations set, then just refresh them after a Deploy to retest.

Comment: Great tip. Unfortunately I verified that the problem is in the SSAS database itself. I'm revising my post to reflect this.